# Log4j - how to tokenize logs like Elastic Search and group by values, filter and visualize them?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

When you know the logging format/pattern, is there a way to visualize/classify/filter logs with certain thread name/client id/... without using Elastic Search? I want to show for example, "this thread has these lines, ordered by timestamp, with these keywords". I don't want to manually search by thread names anymore.

I can manually `grep`, of course, but I want to visualize them in a better way. I can search them if I know the thread names, but I want to show all of the thread names without knowing them previously.

Also, ES marks session boundary, but grep does not. You can see that a session/request is different from another, because the session id has changed. A thread can undertake several sessions in a period of time.

I have only seen that in ES for now. I think it can be called as a log tokenizer and classifier tool, but towards static log files which haven't been fed into ES.

Now, I am trying to do this in Excel: adding `;` between tags, and parse them to columns, and classify/filter. In the screenshot, thread names is filtered to be one. But I found it very hard to do if logs are too many because separating by space is not good, need to manually add `;` or other unique separator.

[image]

Comment: You can try [Chainsaw](https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/).

Comment: Oh... I missed that. Thanks. I think that is what I want, even I need to check how to define the parsing pattern.

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. But a simple pattern like `(%t)` does not resolve the correct name when the thread name contains more than one layer of parenthesis. For example, if thread name is like `(Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - JmsConsumer[my.queue])` or `(Camel (camel-1) thread #17 - Split)`, it stops prematurely. Any idea? BTW you can answer below and I will accept it. I think this is what I need right now.

Comment: That's a bug you [should report](https://github.com/apache/logging-chainsaw/issues).

Comment: Thanks. Submitted a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j2 has a companion project to visualize logs: [Chainsaw](https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/). It does not have a lot of features, but it might be enough for your needs.